# C++ - extending a data type

Tags: c++, arrays, methods, char, extend

Is there a way to extend a data type in C++, like you can in JavaScript?

I would imagine this is kind of like this:

```
char data[]="hello there";
char& capitalize(char&)
{
    //Capitalize the first letter. I know that there
    //is another way such as a for loop and subtract
    //whatever to change the keycode but I specifically 
    //don't want to do it that way. I want there
    //to be a method like appearance.
}

printf("%s", data.capitalize());
```

This should somehow print.

Comment: Not in C++. But you could do something like `capitalize(data)`.

Comment: If the datatype in question is a struct/class, you can (but probably shouldn't) inherit from it. For a built-in type like `int` or `char` (or array thereof) you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: I dont think the's much to do with primitive types. But for classes you can just make some java style stuff and make all of them to implement a lets say 'Printable' interface with given methods toString(), capitalize() ecc :/ 

Or you can just make a template or static function to pass the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is using operator overloading, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

std::string operator!(const std::string& in) {
  std::string out = in;
  std::transform(out.begin(), out.end(), out.begin(), (int (*)(int)) std::toupper);
  return out;
}

int main() {
  std::string str = "hello";
  std::cout << !str << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Alternative approaches include creating a class with `operator std::string` overloaded and a constructor to initialize it using an `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to this in C++. The closest to this in my opinion would be to create a class that acts like the built in type but would provide additional functionality. It's never possible to make them work 100% like the built-in types though so "surrogate" types are not always ideal.

Comment: this is a good answer and probably the best solution but im on the fence about giving it a mark because i don't want to mislead others, but ye a class SString   (special string) or something similar might be needed and inside it i can create what ever

Answer (score 0):

No, [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) is based on prototypes for objects. This concept does not apply for [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29). They are such different languages I can't even show you a counterexample for your question.

Comment: lol thanks for the help i knew this one was going to be challenging. I'm wondering what could be the closest we come to that solution. i guess using a new class.